# TYPO3 v10: How to remove meta tag generator?

Tags: api, typo3, hook, meta-tags, typo3-10.x

```
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS" />
```

I could use the Meta Tag API

```
    $metaTagManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MetaTagManagerRegistry::class)->getManagerForProperty('generator');
    $metaTagManager->removeProperty('generator');
```

but I would need some Default Controller/Action for all Pages which I dont have.

maybe I can hook into the PageRenderer, but how can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure? The documentation says: "To use the manager, you must register it in ext_localconf.php:" (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/MetaTagApi/Index.html#creating-your-own-metatagmanager). So you only need any extension (like your sitepackage).

Answer (score 0):

One of the features of [`sourceopt` extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sourceopt) available in official extension repository is the possibility to remove the generator meta. Just install it with Extension Manager in the backend, then enable with these lines in the Setup field of your TypoScript template probably on the root page (optionally after including extensions TS in your template go to `Constants editor` to click the options):

```
config.sourceopt.enabled = 1
config.sourceopt.removeGenerator = 1
```

**Bonus tip:** check the extension's manual for more options like removing comments or formatting/minimizing output HTML.